# Safe chemical reactions to start a campfire

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

I'm looking for a way to start a small fire electronically with widely available chemicals. It would be great if they are safe to use with metals (not necessarily). But the biggest requirement is that it should be SAFE at medium scales and should not make an explosion.

I have found out $\ce{H2SO4 + KMnO4}$ can start a fire. But is it possible to do it with diluted H2SO4 because concentrated is not safe to handle?

NB: I only want a small ignition. The rest can be continued with some fuel, I believe.

Also, I doesn't possibly need to be a chemical reaction. Anything that can trigger a safe fire is enough

Comment: What is wrong with LPG based or petrol based lighters ? They are cheap, safe and used for these purposes all the time. They are not vulnerable as matches are, when get wet.

Comment: I want to start it electronically. Like it starts the fire when a button is clicked like so... I can throw some safe chemicals with an electronic valve. Fuel from another valve. Like a little home automation...

Comment: That is kind of weird, potentially very unsafe and abusable. If something goes wrong, you can arrive at the burning house.

Comment: This is purely experimental and I'll be the only user... But chemicals are altogether unsafe, right? But I'd like it to be as safe as possible... There must be some safer way.. :) And I won't be doing anything inside unless it's VERY SAFE.

Comment: Obviously, Extinguishers will be ready to put it off if something goes wrong

Comment: I have meant it in the general fire-control safety context, but managing chemicals can bring another factor of their accidental contact. As Gandalf from the LOTR said, Even the wisest cannot see all ends.

Comment: @Poutnik I understand... But imagine if no one invented car engines because it work gas or petrol  aren't we scientists crazy enough to do stupid things to learn new stuff?

Comment: The mixture made with pure and dry $\ce{H2SO4 + KMnO4}$ produces $\ce{Mn2O7}$, and only with dry substances. This $\ce{Mn2O7}$ is able to start a fire with any organic impurity around due to the oxygen produced by its own decomposition into $\ce{MnO2 + O2}$. But if there is even a small amount of water, $\ce{Mn2O7}$ is not produced, because $\ce{Mn2O7}$ is due to the dehydration of $\ce{HMnO4}$ that is the first intermediate product in the initial mixture. And no fire can be started.

Comment: @Maurice So that means I must use highly concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ right? I don't that would be safe to be left unattended! Hard to get too!

Comment: I think I have found the safest solution with physics... A steel would would create some fire when electricity is conducted... I hope some fuel can take over from there...

Comment: @AjithGopi Gas engines do not work with open fire....... With open fire, many things can happen and not all can be easily predicted. It is required to be under direct human control for reason, no matter how it started.

Comment: I would not use the mixture $\ce{KMnO4 + H2SO4}$. It is rather corrosive. It may explode without any reason.

Comment: I understand that @Poutnik, You know automation doesn't work like that... We study, find errors, and improve the system. It will only be left unattended if everything is completely safe.. If it's not safe, the project will be postponed until a better solution is made... :) But right now, I think using the steel wool is completely safe. It only needs around 9v and a few drop of petrol might be enough to let the fire take over wood...

Comment: The problem is that self-igniting binary chemicals are mostly safety risk even if separated. I guess electronically ignited fuel like you mention would be safer.

Comment: Most sophisticated approaches to finding a "sexy" chemical solution are likely unsafe, especially compared to long standing solutions we already know work well *and* are acceptably safe. Like matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small magnesium metal bars are available commercially, packed with a little iron rod for starting fires. You smack the magnesium with the iron rod and get some sparks. If you have some light fluffy kindling, you are supposed to be able to get a fire going. I suppose a little steel wool would help.

If you soak some cotton balls with KNO$_3$, dry them completely and carry them in a sealed plastic bag, they would make excellent kindling.

Comment: Pencil shavings also work well as kindling. Though maybe pencils are not used much now.

Comment: @Ed V: Actually, that's a very good idea! So, buy a 36 inch x 1/4 inch dowel, cut it into 9 inch pieces (or 6 inch), and get one of those little pencil sharpeners. That should make nice fluffy kindling, without paint or "lead".

Comment: I like those old school hand crank pencil sharpeners that used to be in every classroom. Of course, I use mechanical pencils (and pens) now, but the dowel refinement is very good as well! And I think they still sell mechanical pencil sharpeners. By the way, I upvoted: the Mg starter method is most reasonable for most folks.

Answer (score 3):

Apply an electric current to a suitable metal powder mix where, at time of employment, one adds sulfur or potassium nitrate to the open mix (that is, never placed in a confined container). This a possible option and follows the common recipe for [flash powder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_powder).

However, given the desired applications of an electric current as a fire starting mechanism, particular metals of interest should be good conductors, as well. This could include already cited Fe, as well as Al, Mg and Zn.

Caution, be very careful even remotely electrically igniting such flash powder mixtures as they can result in a quite vigorous thermal reaction. This may potentially result in burns. However, in situations where a common magnesium spark fire-starter, for example, is not working (cold or moisture issues), such a composition may be solely successful.

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with a solution to use steel wool with electric power. Steel wool can generate sparks when electricity is passed through. I hope some fuel can take over from there to start a fire. This might have become off-topic here but I hope someone would find it useful.

Anyways, now I know it's not safe to use $\ce{KMnO4 + H2SO4}$

Comment: There would be fine balance between ability to be reproducibly ignited and vapor ability to explode.

Comment: +1. A good reference: https://frugalfun4boys.com/burn-steel-wool-science/

Comment: Your proposed solution is well known. A simple chemical way is to use a gram or so of potassium permanganate and add a few drops of glycerin (glycerol). But the magnesium fire starter method in the answer by James Gaidis is better than carrying around chemicals: potassium permanganate stains whatever it touches and glycerin is sweet, so it attracts insects, especially ants.